# NServiceBus with SQL Server Message Transport

Tags: .net, sql-server, nservicebus, esb

Is there any way to use SQL Server as physical message transport instead of using built in MSMQ message transport with NServiceBus ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to look into implementing a custom ITransport to accomplish this.

Answer (score 3):

SQL Server contains built-in messaging in form of [Service Broker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345108%28SQL.90%29.aspx). This gives you a vary efficient, high-speed, high-throughput, asynchronous and **reliable** messaging transport between SQL Server instances. The fact that is only targeting SQL instances is not as bad as it sounds, considering that SQL Server Express support Service Broker and I know deployments that use tens, hundreds of Express, instances geo-distributed, to exchange messages with central higher edition SQL instances.

The major problem is lack of a C#/.Net API, there is no support for WCF channels, nor NServiceBus. There are various projects trying to address this, with more or less success.
Ultimately it will depend on what is the driving factor for the decision: integration with an existing messaging bus like NServiceBus, or raw performance and reliability at the cost of depending on sQL Server proprietary bus.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry for answering such an old topic, but there is a .Net message bus project using SQL server as a message transport: NGinn.MessageBus (at http://code.google.com/p/nginn-messagebus/ ). It's my pet open source project created specifically for applications that are already using SQL Server. The project is mature enough to be used in production. More information can be found at the project website.

Answer (score 3):

In NServiceBus 3.0 we have made plugging in your own transport mechanism much easier compared to 2.6.  In 2.6 you would implement the ITransport interface wich is huge. In 3.0 you would only need to implement ISendMessages and IReceiveMessages

https://github.com/NServiceBus/NServiceBus/blob/master/src/unicast/NServiceBus.Unicast.Queuing/ISendMessages.cs

https://github.com/NServiceBus/NServiceBus/blob/master/src/unicast/NServiceBus.Unicast.Queuing/IReceiveMessages.cs

Comment: Do you know of an example implementation you could point me to?

Comment: Look at the sssb transport in the nservicebus-contrib (at github). The master branch is a 3.0 impl and the 2.5 branch is a 2.5 impl

Comment: n.b. 3.0 branch is no longer a free product.

Comment: Not sqlserver either:) technically nsb 3.0 free on one server

Comment: I really like this approach. But at the first seight, sorry I'm a NSB newbie, seems NServiceBus.Unicast.Transport.Transactional.Config.Bootstrapper will be always called as built in Transport and it has an hardcoded reference to MsmqTransportConfig. I can't belive I need to use MsmqTransportConfig xml node within config file to define generic transport parameter such NumberOfWorkerThreads or MaxRetries if I implemented a non MSMQ "trasport"

Comment: The 4.0 codebase now contains official support for SqlServer, ActiveMq, RabbitMq and WebSphereMq.

Comment: Thanks Adreas. I ran successfully 4.0 using RabbitMq. I found an issue concernign error handling: if an handler throw an exception, NSB stop polling the queue: it just handle msgs dequeued in a "batch" according to TransportConfig MaximumConcurrencyLevel. Same code works as expected using msmq. Where can I post the issue?

Comment: I also tried using sqlserver as Transport and works smooth fine dealing properly w/ exception... so far only transport not dealing properly remains RabbitMq

Comment: Open up a issue on github. What version are you on? Pretty sure we fixed this recently on the develop branch

Comment: I'm using the version at https://github.com/NServiceBus/NServiceBus/tree/4.0.0. I'll try the dev branch https://github.com/NServiceBus/NServiceBus/tree/develop and I'll let you know. Thanks!

Comment: @Andreas Testing against develop everything works w/ no problem. Thanks a lot... any idea about releasing date for 4.0?

Answer (score 3):

On NServiceBus 4.0 you can now just use [Sql Server as a transport](http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/sqlserver/) mechanism so you don't have to implement ITransport and such.

Comment: I've been trying to get NServiceBus integrated with SSB but so far I haven't any luck with it. Do you know of any good NServiceBus 4 + SSB guide? Thanks